# Convert Unix timestamp to date in React during map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, unix

I have a list of objects that I am mapping over to display the news on a page. The problem is the date comes to me in Unix timestamp instead of correct date format. I am trying to convert it, but every method I can find is only converting 1 item from the list.

I've tried 2 different ways so far

1st way:

```
return (
        <Container>
            {records &&
                records.map((record, index) => {
                    const update = new Date(records.datetime * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
                    return (
                       <span>{record.update}</span>
                    ))};
       </Container>
);
```

2nd way

```
import timestamp from 'unix-timestamp';

<span>{timestamp.toDate(record.datetime)}</span>
```

Comment: i think it would be `record` not `records`.

`const update = new Date(record.datetime * 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you don't use `update`. Also, you are referencing `records` instead of `record` inside your loop.

Try this:

```
return (
        <Container>
            {records &&
                records.map((record, index) => {
                    const update = new Date(record.datetime * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-US');
                    return (
                       <span>{update}</span>
                    ))};
       </Container>
);
```